# Passing a string to SQL as a list of as ('Value1','Value2', etc) and use the IN operator

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm passing in a list as a string to a stored proc of format `"('Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3')"` and storing it in @Type.

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to say something like

`Select * from whatever where colName in @Type` where @Type is that formatted list.

I know this is going to be simple enough that I'll facepalm but "How do?"

Comment: What happens if you put brackets around @Type?

Comment: This is probably the second most asked question after 'how do I turn columns into rows'. Here's a multitude of solutions that I found after a quick search. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-a-sql-in-clause. If you need help implementing any of those please post back.

Comment: @DanBracuk: square or angled?

Comment: What @DanBracuk meant is `in (@Type)`

Comment: I didn't notice that you had the brackets as part of the varialble.  Even if it you get this working worked with something like 'fred', 'barney', 'wilma', you would still need to do something to escape apostrophes.

Comment: Yeah, sql isn't my strongest suit. I've edited my question to include the actual code I'm trying to modify with @DanBracuk's suggestion included

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: I'm not the strongest at SQL so I'm not sure any of the solutions in the link you posted actually does what I need it to.

Comment: http://sqlperformance.com/split & http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql

Comment: @AaronBertrand: You understood *exactly* what I was trying to say even though I didn't know how to word it correctly. I'm going through that now and I have control over how the list gets passed to the proc. If I can get this to work using what you posted, please post as an answer and I'll accept it as the answer to my problem. Thank you.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Your suggestions have worked. If you want to repost your suggestion as an answer, I'll mark is as the accepted answer and explain why it's correct to anyone else that comes behind...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps at all but what if you use a `table type variable` like

```
DECLARE @MyTable table(
    col1 varchar(10) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO @MyTable(col1)
select 'Value1'
union
select 'Value2'
union
select 'Value3';
```

Then fetch data

```
Select * from whatever where colName in (select col1 from @MyTable)
```